# Django how to select multiple columns on a single model instance

Tags: django, model

This seems like something simple that I've overlooked, but here goes anyway.

I have a model defined, and I want to retrieve certain columns from the model (NOT via QuerySet API/model manager), but within the model class.

Example:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    col1 = ...
    col2 = ...
    col3 = ...

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.col1, self.col3) # Notice I'm omitting col2.
```

In the `__unicode__` class method this counts as at least 2 DB queries. How can I retrieve col1 and col3 within this class method in only 1 DB query? Seems like it should be so simple, that I feel like I'm doing something dumb.

UPDATE:

Based on the feedback, I created a test model, test form, etc... and found what several users stated is correct. However, in my *actual* code (using multiple forms), changing the `__unicode__` method to return a column of concatenated values changed the number of SQL queries went from 601 to 34. I only changed that single line. Based on my test cases, perhaps something else is going on, but to reiterate, *I only changed the unicode method* and I got a drastically different quantity of DB hits.

I'm not sure what is going on with my other code and I'll have to try and look at it closer. In the mean time here are the test cases, which prove you guys are correct:

```
# Models.py
class TestModelFK(models.Model):
    col1    = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    col2    = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    col3    = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    col4    = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    allcols = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, editable=False)    

    class Meta:
        ordering        = ('col1', 'col2')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.col1, self.col2, self.col3, self.col4)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.allcols    = '%s %s %s %s' % (self.col1, self.col2, self.col3, self.col4)

        super(TestModelFK, self).save()

class TestModel(models.Model):
    quantity    = models.IntegerField()
    test_fk     = models.ForeignKey(TestModelFK)


# forms.py
class TestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = TestModel


# views.py
if request.method == 'GET':
    post['TestModelFormSet'] = formset_factory(TestModelForm, extra=4)
```

Comment: -1 since the premise is simply false.

Comment: You should always return a unicode object from `__unicode__` and not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your function:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.col1, self.col3) # Notice I'm omitting col2.
```

By the time you invoke `__unicode__`, you already have your model in memory. You may access the fields from `self` as much as you want, there's no database access from this point.

Answer (score 1):

`__unicode__` method call is happens as a in-memory call. It doesn't trigger a separate DB call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're doing this

```
myModelInstance = MyModel.objects().get(id=1)
```

and then

```
print myModelInstance
>> "WhateverCol1is WhateverCol2is"
```

This would absolutely trigger 1 database call, since you have to fetch that model instance.
This is what `get()` does, it fetches the object straight away.

Since you've omitted your field declarations I am guessing that either `col1` or `col3` is either a `ManyToMany` field or a `ForeignKey`, thus when fetching the instance it'll fetch the rows that the fields refer to.

If you have a QuerySet that's done like this

```
myModelInstances = MyModel.objects().filter(id=1)
```

and iterate over it, it will evaluate it and require *n* database calls.

QuerySets are lazy and only evaluates (ie. goes to the database) when certain things happen, these being

- Iterating over a QuerySet
- Slicing a QuerySet
- Using `list()` on a QuerySet
- Using `len()`
- Using `repr()`
- And pickling or caching a QuerySet

Read more about the [QuerySet here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: Sorry to make you guess. I didn't have all the info until I got some feedback. But overall I was calling the `__unicode__` method through a choicefield in a modelform. If you see my additional comments, I'm not sure why I am observing the behavior I'm seeing since my test case fails to reproduce the issue that my actual code is exhibiting.